# How can I apply CSS Style to my second page [about.php]?

Tags: php, html, css

My File names:
1.) about.php
2.) styles.css

The same stylesheet is also applied to index.php .

I want to style the section part of the page. I tried it by styling the [Eg.], .section-info{color:#555;}

but it didn't helped. Also should I change the stylesheet name to styles.php? 
Thanks In Advance.

```html
<?php

/* Website Header */

    include ("include/header.php");
    
?>

<!-- Website Page-2 Main Content -->

<div class="wrapper">

                
            <section>
                <div class="section-info">
                    <h2>About Us</h2>
                        <p>blah...blah...bllah....</p>
                </div>
                
            </section>
           
    </div>
                    
   
 <?php
    /* Website Footer */
    
    include ("include/footer.php");
?>
```

Comment: No dont change it to styles.php ist still a cascading style sheet and not a php file.

Comment: Show your `include/header.php` file

Comment: it would help us if you show your header.php file

Comment: If you're confident that all of your code within the head of the HTML markup is correct, and you're sure that header.php is being included correctly, not misspelled, etc, then hit CTRL + SHIFT + R on Windows, in Chrome. This will Hard Refresh and will make sure your CSS Stylesheet isn't being cached at an older version

Comment: @HarryKitchener your idea worked the background color changed when I pressed (CTRL + SHIFT + R) on Windows.

Comment: Thanks to all of you guys. :)

Comment: changing the name of the style-sheet from [styles.css to styles.php],  is a good practice please guys share your views.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give it different class or inline style.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I created a [function here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/159854/69564) which I use.

Then I use `$page = getPage("ab")` which would return `about` and then you can check what page is in use using the below:

```
<?php
$page = getPage("ab");
if ($page == "about") { ?>
<style type="text/css">
    .section-info {
        background: #f00;
    }
</style>
<?php } ?>
```

Put this code inside the `<head>` of your `about.php` page. This will apply whatever code you want to that page.